# passing javascript parameter word to a custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have made a very simple custom Jquery function that reset the inline style of an html element. But, I want to be able to pass a parameter to be excluded so the "reset" will avoid it.

```
$.fn.resetCss = function(b) {
    if (b != 'undefined'){
      let a=this.style.b;
    }

    this.removeAttr('style');

    if(b != 'undefined') {
      this.style.b = a;
    }
  }
```

But then I got error by passing (for example) height.

- I have tried `if(b)` instead of testing if `undefined`
- eval(b) returns me `height is not defined`

Here is a snipet to try it out:

```js
$('button').on('click',function() {
  $('div').resetCss(height);
});
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.fn.resetCss = function(b) {
    if (b){
      let a=this.style.b;
    }

    this.removeAttr('style');

    if(b) {
      this.style.b = a;
    }
  }
</script>

<button>go</button>
<div style='width:200px;height:100px;'>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, in association with eval to get a "javascript var" (kinda) but it doesn't work ;(

Comment: @Craicerjack That could be, but it still returns me `Cannot read property 'height' of undefined`

Comment: `this` is a jQuery object. jQuery has no `style` property. so `this.style.anything` will result in a null-reference exception.

Comment: I find your `resetCss()` method somewhat counter-intuitive as it would reset all styles except for the one you pass. That's not the behaviour I would have expected.

Comment: @Thomas answer that, and tells that I have to use jquery functions in my extended one (resetCss) so I can give you the +rep ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, `this` is a jQuery object. jQuery has no `style` property. so `this.style.anything` will result in a null-reference exception.

I've also updated your function.

```js
$.fn.resetCss = function() {
  var stylesToKeep = [].slice.call(arguments);

  if (stylesToKeep.length > 0) {
    this.each(function() {
      let styles = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < stylesToKeep.length; ++i) {
        let key = stylesToKeep[i],
          value = this.style[key];
        // don't copy undefined and empty values
        if (value) {
          styles[key] = value;
        }
      }
      this.removeAttribute("style");
      Object.assign(this.style, styles);
    });
  } else {
    this.removeAttr('style');
  }

  return this;
}


$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('div').resetCss("height");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>go</button>
<div style='width:200px;height:100px;'>
</div>
```

Comment: mmh, that update is good, but so you keep the logic as so? Thank you btw, that is perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define height variable at least once.Like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var height = 0;
  $('button').on('click',function() {
     $('div').resetCss(height);
  });
  $.fn.resetCss = function(b) {
   
      if (b){
        let a=this.style.b;
      }

      this.removeAttr('style');

      if(b) {
        this.style.b = a;
      }
    }
 })
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>go</button>
<div style='width:200px;height:100px;'>
</div>
```

Comment: except its not about the height its about any variable. So while this might work for height it wont work in general

Comment: And I don't want height as a variable, I need THE `height` param that javascript can understand when I tell him `this.style.height = 100` for example (check the jquery extended function resetCss in my code)